# Qual a Diferença no Grails entre run-app e run.Aplication do IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Estou trabalhando a 1 ano com Grails e IntelliJ Community 14, e venho notando alguns comportamentos diferentes entre rodar o projeto através da linha de comando e utilizar o Run 'Aplication.main()' do IDEA.

Posto essa dúvida para tentar entender de uma vez que diferença é essa. Vou tentar exemplificar com uma situação que me deparei ultimamente.

Pense em duas Entidades. Uma "Servico" e outra "Status", conforme abaixo:

```
class Servico {

   static hasOne = [status: Status]

   static constraints = {
﻿﻿       status nullable: true
﻿   }
}﻿

class Status {

   String nome
﻿﻿   static hasMany = [servicos: Servico]

   static constraints = {
      nome nullable: false, unique: true
   }
}
```

O projeto funciona normalmente rodando pelo IDEA, porém quando utilizado o run-app da linha de comando, o seguinte erro ocorre ao tentar salvar um "Servico":

object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: projeto.Status

O que já não faz muito sentido, uma vez que o Status já existe na base antes do Serviço.

Depois disso, ao tentar rodar o projeto novamente no IDEA, outro erro ocorre de cara:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in projeto.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/gorm/Entity

Para conseguir rodar novamente, preciso usar um "grails clean". Após esse comando (ou excluir a pasta build) o projeto volta a funcionar corretamente.

Aparentemente o IDEA está gerando uma pasta build diferente da pasta gerada pelo run-app.

Alguém tem alguma luz a respeito disso?